# Best way to sort and handle tweets - Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, twitter

The below code successfully returns tweets and twitter data, my question is now what is the best way to sort and return specifics from the twitter array, such as those specified in sortTweets(). The main issue I am encountering at the moment is that due to the asynchronous nature of the twitter API and JS, I am not sure how to specify the function to wait until getTweets() has returned the necessary data which can then be sorted and trimmed down to the tweet, the user etc. Is this the best way to go about this or would it be easier to sort the tweets within the handleTweets() function?

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var client = new Twit({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token: '',
  access_token_secret: '',
  timeout_ms: 60*1000,
});

var count = 10,
    profile = 'manutd',
    date = '2011-11-11',
    keyword = 'man city',
    lan = 'en',
    search = keyword + " since:" + date + " lang:" + lan;

var tweets = getTweets();
var profiles = getProfile();
console.log('Started')
//var sortedTweets = sortTweets(tweets);
//console.log(sortedTweets)

function handleTweets(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  }  
  else {
    console.log('Get Tweets');
    //console.log(data);
    console.log('Finished');
  }
}

function handleFriends(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  }  
  else {
    console.log('Get Friends');
    //console.log(data);
    console.log('Finished');
  }
}

function sortTweets (err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Get error', err)
    }
    else if (getTweets.ready){
      for (var indx in data.statuses){
          var tweet = data.statuses[indx];
          console.log('on: ' + tweet.created_at + ' : @' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' : ' + tweet.text+'\n\n');
      }
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(sortTweets,100);
    }
}


function getTweets(){
  return client.get('search/tweets', { q: search, count: count, from: profile },
              handleTweets)

}

function getProfile( callback ){
  return client.get('friends/list', { screen_name: profile, count: count },
             handleFriends)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways work, but I would suggest handling the sorting directly in the `handleTweets()` function, as you can be sure that when the `sortTweets()` function is called you will either have received a response with the data or an error which can be handled.

Additionally I would suggest reading this: http://callbackhell.com/, as parts of your code suggest you are not to familiar with callbacks and the async part of NodeJS, which is indeed rather tricky when first worked with.

**EDIT:**

Your `handleTweets` and `sortTweets` functions could look something like this:

```
function handleTweets(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  } else {
    console.log('Get Friends');
    //console.log(data);
    console.log('Finished, no error, data is ready');
    sortTweets(data);
  }
}

function sortTweets (data) {
  for (var indx in data.statuses){
    var tweet = data.statuses[indx];
    console.log('on: ' + tweet.created_at + ' : @' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' : ' + tweet.text+'\n\n');
  }
}
```

No guarantees on the correctness of the code, just a rough example of what it could look like.

Comment: I will definitely read through that thank you. Is it possible to take the else if section of sortTweets() and incorporate it into handleTweets()?

Comment: Updated answer with a suggestion